# Visual Studio C++ Ignores lines in if statements or if statements entirely. VS 2015

Tags: c++, visual-studio, if-statement

This does not happen in any other IDE I use, only VS.

It ignores the 'std::cout' in the if statement and sometimes it ignores the if statement all together.

To demonstrate I put together a simple program.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>

void main()
{
    char Auth_Key_Requested[10];
    std::cout << " Enter Auth_Key { : } : ";
    std::cin >> Auth_Key_Requested;
    if (Auth_Key_Requested == " K3knksh ")
    {
        std::cout << " Auth_Key_Requested == True, GJ.\n ";
        Sleep(5000);
        exit(0);
    } else if (Auth_Key_Requested != " K3knksh ")
    {
        Sleep(5000);
        exit(0);
    }
}
```

Replies and answers would help greatly.

Comment: You cannot compare a string like that with a C array

Comment: how do you know it "ignores" the line? I doubt that. I think it's probably just buffering, and you ignore how iostreams work. Or your business logic is wrong. A run in the debugger with a breakpoint will demonstrate either.

Comment: s/`Auth_Key_Requested == " K3knksh "`/`strcmp(Auth_Key_Requested," K3knksh ")`

Comment: Use `std::string` and then you can compare. It's more difficult if you are not permitted to use `c++`

Comment: And: I know this is just a minimal example, but there's some problem with it. Just in case the checking of a key is really happening in your code: You must **never** try to check a password by comparing it to an internally stored string. It literally takes split seconds for anyone to find that string, seconds if you obfuscate it, or microseconds if you subject your program to a debugger (even without debugging symbols). There's tools that do such things automatically to test large sets of binaries for such obvious security shortcomings.

Comment: @drescherjm well, all of the program is C++, I don't see how he could write that program without C++. Riding a car is very hard when you're not allowed to use a car, too.

Comment: @Marcus Muller, That's the whole point, I am trying to make it so its easy to find with a Hex editor.

Comment: @MAXBD the Unix tool you're looking for is `strings`, and it takes a file as argument. Anyway, you can do that with `std::string` instead of `char` arrays just as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not ignore the if case, it just evaluates the condition to false. The way you compare C-Style Strings (which are strings in primitive char arrays) is wrong. The right way to do it is with the function strcmp. This function takes two C-Style strings and returns 0, if they are the same. Positive and negative values are explained [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcmp/).
So your if statement should read as follows:

```
if (strcmp(Auth_Key_Requested, " K3knksh ") == 0)
{
    std::cout << " Auth_Key_Requested == True, GJ.\n ";
    Sleep(5000);
    exit(0);
} else
{
    Sleep(5000);
    exit(0);
}
```